# Let, $V$ be a vector subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Prove that, $V$ is a closed set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with respect to usual metric.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let, $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k\}$ be a basis for $V$. Let, $\{v_n\}$ be sequence of vectors in $V$ such that $v_j\to v$ where $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$. My target is to prove $v\in V$.
Now for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$, $v_j=\lambda_{1j}u_1+\lambda_{2j}u_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{kj}u_{k}$.
Since $\{v_j\}$ converges in $\Bbb{R}^n$, it is cauchy in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Now I want to say the sequences $\{\lambda_{1j}\},\{\lambda_{2j}\},\ldots,\{\lambda_{kj}\}$ are all cauchy (hence convergent) in $\Bbb{R}$. So, that taking $n\to\infty$, we will get $v=\lim_{j\to\infty}\lambda_{1j}u_1+\lambda_{2j}u_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{kj}u_{k}=\lambda_1 u_1+\lambda_2 u_2+\cdots+\lambda_k u_k\in V$ where $\lambda_i=\lim_{j\to\infty}\lambda_{ij}$.
Now, $|v_j-v_m|\le |\lambda_{1j}-\lambda_{1m}||u_1|+|\lambda_{2j}-\lambda_{2m}||u_2|+\cdots+|\lambda_{kj}-\lambda_{km}||u_k|$
$\le M(|\lambda_{1j}-\lambda_{1m}|+|\lambda_{2j}-\lambda_{2m}|+\cdots+|\lambda_{kj}-\lambda_{km}|)$ where $M=max\{|u_i|\}$
But from this, I cannot say each $\{\lambda_{ij}\}$ is Cauchy. Can anyone complete the solution? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: a remark: You would have to use the fact that $\{u_i\}_i$ is a linearly indepdent set, for otherwise, the claim wouldn't follow.

Comment: Yes, I have chosen $\{u_i\}_i$ to be basis

Comment: @ArnabRoy what that person means is that everything you wrote down afterwards is still true even if $u_i$ only spans $V$

Comment: Ok, but how to finish the proof  using the fact $\{u_i\}_i$ is linearly independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume $u_i$ are orthonormal, by the Gram-Schmidt procedure. Extend to a full orthonormal basis $u_1,\dots, u_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Write $v=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i. $Then for each $i> k$,
$$
|\lambda_i| =|(v_j-v)\cdot u_i|\le |v_j - v|\xrightarrow[j\to\infty]{}0.
$$
Therefore $v=\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i u_i$ i.e. $v$ belongs to $V$.

Comment: NB in my answer $v_j$ is the element of the sequence of vectors, $n$ is the dimension. You have a notation clash because you wrote $v_n$ and also $\mathbb R^{\color{red} n}$

Comment: Yes I understand, I am also thinking with orthogonal vectors. Really appreciate the answer thanks for the help.